# Como detener un for si se cumple una condicion en C++?

Tags: c++, bucle-for, condiciones, bucles

Tengo este fragmento de codigo con for anidados, y quiero que se detengan una vez se cumpla la condicion del if para que me queden esos valores guardados en a y en b, y no siga iterando.

Como puedo hacer para que si se cumple la condicion, paren todos los for?

(Con los ejemplos que estoy utilizando se que deberia de parar en a=5 y b=7, pero no para cuando se cumplen esos valores)

contadorp = 7

```
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < 26; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < contadorp; k++){
            if((i*int(palabra[k])+j)%26 + 65 == int(texto[k])){
            a = i;
            b = j;
            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Probando con codigo por separado, me di cuenta de que nunca entra al if (no se por que, porque la condicion se cumple)

Por ejemplo, probando con el primer caracter de cada string:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 26; a++)
    for(int b = 1; b < 26; b++)
            if(((a*int(palabra[0])+b)%26 + 65) == (int(texto[0]))){
            break;
            printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
            }

printf("%c %c\n", texto[0], palabra[0]);

printf("%d %d", (5*int(palabra[0])+7)%26 + 65, int(texto[0]));
```

Si pongo como entrada en texto: OGLQJIM
Y en entrada en palabra: ESTUDIO

Da como salida

O E

79 79

Lo cual es correcto, pero no entiendo por que no entra a la condicion de if si es la misma que probe aqui por separado, solo que con el primer indice.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes por ejemplo utilizar una variable buleana y utilizarla en el while de los bucles for. Algo así:

```
int encontrado = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 26 && !encontrado; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < 26 && !encontrado; j++){
        for(int k = 0; k < contadorp && !encontrado; k++){
            if((i*int(palabra[k])+j)%26 + 65 == int(texto[k])){
                a = i;
                b = j;
                encontrado = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

De hecho seguramente sobre el break. Llevo mucho tiempo sin tocar c y no tengo un compilador a mano.

He utilizado int en lugar de bool, que es lo que normalmente haría, con *#include<stdbool.h>*

Comment: Buenas, gracias por la respuesta! 
El problema es que no puedo utilizar otra libreria que no sea #include <stdio.h>, de todas formas intente con el codigo que me mandaste, cambia los resultados de a y de b pero no me da los que necesito. 
Puede ser tambien un problema con el recorrido del k hasta contadorp? Asi esta bien o deberia de ir ese for antes que los otros?

Comment: @cantomauro Esa solución no usa ninguna librería, solo añade una variable tipo int (que podria ser bool), así que no entiendo el comentario.
Si no da lo que necesitas, el problema debe ser otro. Si invierte los valores de a y b, pero no es lo que necesitas, ¿que necesitas?

Comment: Tal como comenta @ArnauCastellví no utilizo bool justo en previsión que no puedas usarlo, utilizo int. Si la solución no hace lo que quieres dinos por favor qué esperabas que ocurriera y qué ocurrió en su lugar

Answer (score -2):

Usar `goto` es una solución adecuada en este caso, aunque hay quienes se oponen por completo a su uso.

```cpp
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < 26; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < contadorp; k++){
                if((i*int(palabra[k])+j)%26 + 65 == int(texto[k])){
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    goto fin_bucle;
                }
            }
        }
    }

fin_bucle:
    ...
```

En el segundo ejemplo sí se llega a cumplir la condición solo que estás usando break antes de `printf`, lo que evita que la función se llame.

Comment: Un goto no es nunca una solución adecuada.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví Decir no es nunca es limitarse al dogma de Dijkstra, usar goto de forma descendente no disminuye la calidad del código ni lo hace ilegible. En lenguages como C (especialmente) y C++, donde es muy frecuente realizar acciones de limpieza antes de retornar de una función, y, dado con no cuentan con un constructo como defer de Golang, no existe alternativa más legible que goto. Igual sucede con los bucles, ya que no existe un constructo break <label>;

Comment: En manos inexpertas provoca mas problemas que soluciones. Uno empieza a usarlos para salir de bucles y termina provocando stackoverflows.

Comment: Venía a decir que utilizar goto no es nunca la solución adecuada, veo que ya se ha dicho y me voy ;-) En 30 años programando no he utilizado nunca uno. Siempre se puede hacer una estructura mejor para que no sea necesario.

Comment: El uso de `goto` está presente en proyectos como Linux, OpenSSL, GCC, coreutils, etc. que ilustran el uso correcto de este constructo. Al parecer en tu trabajo no has tenido que lidiar con situaciones en que sí resulta más apto usar `goto` antes que anidar o repetir fragmentos de código excesivamente. Por cierto, no estoy negando la facilidad con que `goto` puede usarse incorrectamente, ni tampoco que `goto` sea una terrible opción en lenguajes más sofisticados o de más alto nivel que C/C++.